Cluster huge amount of locations
I have huge amount of locations (about 300000), and I need to cluster them based on distance to display in map. Do you know any solutions for this?
Some preconditions:

The number of locations is varies for each users, so each users will have a different clusters.
Each zoom_level need different clusters (we have 19 level of zoom)

I tried using supercluster library, it works really well but has some drawbacks:

The loading time is kinda slow (about 3s). But after all locations are loaded, it fetch really fast. And when the loading process is running, cpu is really high (about 90%). So if we cluster for multiple users at the same time, the server may be down.
I tried to cache the clusters for each user, so everytime user fetch clusters, I just need to take it from cache, but the thing is it takes so much RAM (clusters for 1 user will take about 200MB), so I dont think this solution works either.

I tried another approach, is using postgis in postgres. (Using ST_CLUSTERDBSCAN), but it runs really slow.

Have you tried running the calculation in the browser rather than on the server? Alternately have you tried clustering only random subsets of a fixed size at any given zoom? (After all you can't display all of them on your map anyways...)

@btilly We are using mobile to display the map, and we tried to let mobile clusters locations by themself. It works fine with less than 80k locations, but if it's larger, it crashes. I think letting the app handle is not a good way, because every time the user enters the map (assume the user uses the lowest zoom level), the server has to return 300k locations to the app. It takes time to receive all locations and increase the transfer cost.
